# Find next image tag based on <a tag

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

Here is my code

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.home.test.com/test/redirector.jspx?      
action=ref&cname=EDITORIAL&ckey=2259303&cc=US&lc=eng&cmpid=MA41335AM"     
style=cursor:hand ;color: #ffffff ;text-decoration:none">

<img height="250" src="http://newsletters.tm.agilent.com/epsg/13MR/MCD-CID/11_CC_020783-   
N9322C/N9322C_Application.jpg" alt="Basic spectrum analyzer" style="padding 0 0 0    
 0;margin:0 0 0 0;"border="0"></a>
```

now the problem is i want to find the img alt attribute text based on href tag.
it is generating dynamically so it can be anything is there any method to find href closest img tag or href next img tag..

Answer (score 0):

Direct child selector would be the best here

```
$('a > img').attr('alt');
```

Comment: i am iterating it within each function so in the whole html i have to find the href and its closest img alt text $(filteredText).find('a[href]').each(function () { var tt = $(this).attr('href'); href += $(this).attr('href') + '~' + $(this).text() + "|"; }) Now i have to find the closest img alt text witin this function